# FORCE CLOSE with HelloTabWidget (Official Android Tutorial)

Tags: android

I've tried all the other posts on here and other places to solve this, but can't get it working.

I'm using the Eclipse IDE, it suggests there are no problems, but once it loads up the virtual device, and the application it force closes.

On advice from another post, I'm just re-running the app with logCat loaded... Well attempting to, Eclipse freezes up sometimes with logCat loaded when I try to run the app.  Also my Virtual Device seems to take a silly long time to boot into the GUI (when loading this App).  I've taken a snapshot of the verbose at this point (not yet loaded GUI)

Link to .zip of files: [http://ge.tt/8KVA0qC]

```
01-27 13:56:43.997: I/DEBUG(31): debuggerd: Jun 30 2010 13:59:20
01-27 13:56:44.145: I/Netd(30): Netd 1.0 starting
01-27 13:56:44.175: I/Vold(29): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
01-27 13:56:44.185: D/qemud(38): entering main loop
01-27 13:56:44.225: D/Vold(29): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
01-27 13:56:44.835: D/Vold(29): Volume sdcard state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
01-27 13:56:44.855: W/Vold(29): No UMS switch available
01-27 13:56:45.025: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
01-27 13:56:45.035: D/qemud(38): created client 0xe078 listening on fd 8
01-27 13:56:45.046: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'boot-properties'
01-27 13:56:45.046: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 1
01-27 13:56:45.067: D/qemud(38): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 1
01-27 13:56:45.067: I/qemu-props(51): connected to 'boot-properties' qemud service.
01-27 13:56:45.085: I/qemu-props(51): received: dalvik.vm.heapsize=24m
01-27 13:56:45.085: I/qemu-props(51): received: qemu.sf.lcd_density=240
01-27 13:56:45.094: I/qemu-props(51): received: qemu.hw.mainkeys=1
01-27 13:56:45.094: I/qemu-props(51): received: qemu.sf.fake_camera=back
01-27 13:56:45.094: I/qemu-props(51): received: 
01-27 13:56:45.094: I/qemu-props(51): invalid format, ignored.
01-27 13:56:45.355: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
01-27 13:56:45.355: D/qemud(38): created client 0x12f38 listening on fd 11
01-27 13:56:45.355: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 11
01-27 13:56:45.385: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
01-27 13:56:45.385: D/qemud(38): created client 0x12f38 listening on fd 11
01-27 13:56:45.385: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'gsm'
01-27 13:56:45.385: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 2
01-27 13:56:45.394: D/qemud(38): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 2
01-27 13:56:46.166: D/AndroidRuntime(33): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
01-27 13:56:46.166: D/AndroidRuntime(33): CheckJNI is ON
01-27 13:56:47.134: I/(34): ServiceManager: 0xacd0
01-27 13:56:47.154: D/AudioHardwareInterface(34): setMode(NORMAL)
01-27 13:56:47.174: I/CameraService(34): CameraService started: pid=34
01-27 13:56:47.216: I/AudioFlinger(34): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb3f0 ready to run
01-27 13:56:47.295: D/AndroidRuntime(33): --- registering native functions ---
01-27 13:56:50.117: I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(33): Profiler is disabled.
01-27 13:56:50.485: I/Zygote(33): Preloading classes...
01-27 13:56:50.501: E/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
01-27 13:56:50.555: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 821 objects / 47496 bytes in 53ms
01-27 13:56:52.485: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 219 objects / 13600 bytes in 29ms
01-27 13:56:53.045: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 253 objects / 14360 bytes in 30ms
01-27 13:56:53.635: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 468 objects / 28984 bytes in 32ms
01-27 13:56:55.722: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2088 objects / 108280 bytes in 47ms
01-27 13:56:57.205: W/MediaProfiles(33): could not find media config xml file
01-27 13:56:57.446: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 279 objects / 15984 bytes in 92ms
01-27 13:56:59.805: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5001 objects / 222304 bytes in 114ms
01-27 13:57:08.631: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 11248 objects / 380304 bytes in 152ms
01-27 13:57:10.665: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9787 objects / 460144 bytes in 160ms
01-27 13:57:12.565: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8696 objects / 424048 bytes in 185ms
01-27 13:57:15.465: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7382 objects / 461032 bytes in 174ms
01-27 13:57:17.865: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7537 objects / 457728 bytes in 180ms
01-27 13:57:21.208: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7392 objects / 457712 bytes in 210ms
01-27 13:57:24.115: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8723 objects / 511496 bytes in 199ms
01-27 13:57:24.676: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 452 objects / 38984 bytes in 140ms
01-27 13:57:25.885: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 594 objects / 28832 bytes in 205ms
01-27 13:57:26.475: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 449 objects / 25152 bytes in 164ms
01-27 13:57:28.225: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 308 objects / 35144 bytes in 246ms
01-27 13:57:29.050: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 279 objects / 18984 bytes in 211ms
01-27 13:57:30.860: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 341 objects / 18472 bytes in 206ms
01-27 13:57:32.215: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 449 objects / 28320 bytes in 173ms
01-27 13:57:35.705: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 529 objects / 53120 bytes in 72ms
01-27 13:57:35.895: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 623 objects / 34000 bytes in 73ms
01-27 13:57:36.125: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 861 objects / 46816 bytes in 76ms
01-27 13:57:36.435: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1747 objects / 85480 bytes in 80ms
01-27 13:57:36.635: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 447 objects / 29384 bytes in 76ms
01-27 13:57:36.826: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 315 objects / 20120 bytes in 81ms
01-27 13:57:36.854: I/Zygote(33): ...preloaded 1265 classes in 46366ms.
01-27 13:57:36.854: E/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
01-27 13:57:36.945: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 104 objects / 14256 bytes in 84ms
01-27 13:57:37.207: I/Zygote(33): Preloading resources...
01-27 13:57:37.245: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080093 (res/drawable-hdpi/sym_def_app_icon.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.265: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080002 (res/drawable-hdpi/arrow_down_float.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.394: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800b3 (res/drawable/btn_check.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.406: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800b6 (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_label_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.415: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800b7 (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_off.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.425: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800bc (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.484: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080004 (res/drawable/btn_default.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.534: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080005 (res/drawable/btn_default_small.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.584: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080006 (res/drawable/btn_dropdown.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.634: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080008 (res/drawable/btn_plus.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.674: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080007 (res/drawable/btn_minus.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.734: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080009 (res/drawable/btn_radio.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.814: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108000a (res/drawable/btn_star.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.904: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 421 objects / 25864 bytes in 87ms
01-27 13:57:37.947: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080131 (res/drawable/btn_toggle.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.955: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080194 (res/drawable-hdpi/ic_emergency.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.974: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080012 (res/drawable-hdpi/divider_horizontal_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:37.984: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080014 (res/drawable-hdpi/divider_horizontal_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.055: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080016 (res/drawable/edit_text.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.095: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108016d (res/drawable/expander_group.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.144: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080062 (res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.144: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080227 (res/drawable-hdpi/menu_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.164: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080228 (res/drawable-hdpi/menu_background_fill_parent_width.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.214: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080229 (res/drawable/menu_selector.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.224: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080234 (res/drawable-hdpi/panel_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.244: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108023b (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_bottom_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.265: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108023c (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_bottom_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.285: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108023d (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_bottom_medium.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.313: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108023e (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_center_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.324: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108023f (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_center_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.344: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080242 (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_full_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.374: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080245 (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_top_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.395: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080246 (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_top_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.444: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108006d (res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.464: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108024c (res/drawable/progress_small.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.484: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108024d (res/drawable/progress_small_titlebar.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.494: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080270 (res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_horizontal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.524: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080271 (res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.624: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 477 objects / 32640 bytes in 99ms
01-27 13:57:38.655: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080071 (res/drawable/spinner_dropdown_background.xml) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.686: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080354 (res/drawable-hdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.695: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d6 (res/drawable-hdpi/indicator_code_lock_drag_direction_green_up.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.715: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d7 (res/drawable-hdpi/indicator_code_lock_drag_direction_red_up.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.738: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d8 (res/drawable-hdpi/indicator_code_lock_point_area_default.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.767: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d9 (res/drawable-hdpi/indicator_code_lock_point_area_green.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.774: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801da (res/drawable-hdpi/indicator_code_lock_point_area_red.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.795: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801e8 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_confirm_gray.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.814: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801ec (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.837: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801ed (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_pressed.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.844: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801f1 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_confirm_gray.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.865: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801f5 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.891: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801f6 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_pressed.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.904: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801fb (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_left_confirm_gray.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.914: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080200 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_left_normal.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.935: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080201 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_left_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.954: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080203 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_right_confirm_gray.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.975: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080209 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_right_normal.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:38.984: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108020a (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_right_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:39.005: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108020d (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_target_gray.png) that varies with configuration!!
01-27 13:57:39.015: I/Zygote(33): ...preloaded 61 resources in 1801ms.
01-27 13:57:39.084: I/Zygote(33): ...preloaded 15 resources in 66ms.
01-27 13:57:39.164: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 503 objects / 37832 bytes in 83ms
01-27 13:57:39.254: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 150 objects / 5784 bytes in 76ms
01-27 13:57:39.354: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2 objects / 48 bytes in 96ms
01-27 13:57:39.395: I/dalvikvm(33): System server process 68 has been created
01-27 13:57:39.406: I/Zygote(33): Accepting command socket connections
01-27 13:57:40.125: E/BatteryService(68): usbOnlinePath not found
01-27 13:57:40.125: E/BatteryService(68): batteryVoltagePath not found
01-27 13:57:40.135: E/BatteryService(68): batteryTemperaturePath not found
01-27 13:57:40.205: I/sysproc(68): Entered system_init()
01-27 13:57:40.205: I/sysproc(68): ServiceManager: 0x122e98
01-27 13:57:40.215: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): SurfaceFlinger is starting
01-27 13:57:40.235: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
01-27 13:57:40.265: E/SurfaceFlinger(68): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): using (fd=25)
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): id           = 
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): xres         = 480 px
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): yres         = 800 px
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): xres_virtual = 480 px
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): yres_virtual = 1600 px
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): bpp          = 16
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): r            = 11:5
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): g            =  5:6
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): b            =  0:5
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): width        = 74 mm (164.756760 dpi)
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): height       = 123 mm (165.203247 dpi)
01-27 13:57:40.405: I/gralloc(68): refresh rate = 60.00 Hz
01-27 13:57:40.465: D/libEGL(68): egl.cfg not found, using default config
01-27 13:57:40.487: D/libEGL(68): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
01-27 13:57:40.525: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): EGL informations:
01-27 13:57:40.525: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): # of configs : 8
01-27 13:57:40.535: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): vendor    : Android
01-27 13:57:40.535: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL
01-27 13:57:40.535: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): extensions: EGL_KHR_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_image_pixmap EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer EGL_ANDROID_swap_rectangle EGL_ANDROID_get_render_buffer 
01-27 13:57:40.535: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): Client API: OpenGL ES
01-27 13:57:40.535: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): EGLSurface: 5-6-5-0, config=0x1000000
01-27 13:57:40.547: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): flags     : 001c0000
01-27 13:57:40.566: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): OpenGL informations:
01-27 13:57:40.566: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): vendor    : Android
01-27 13:57:40.566: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): renderer  : Android PixelFlinger 1.3
01-27 13:57:40.566: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): version   : OpenGL ES-CM 1.0
01-27 13:57:40.566: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): extensions: GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ANDROID_user_clip_plane GL_ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object GL_ANDROID_generate_mipmap 
01-27 13:57:40.566: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 4096
01-27 13:57:40.566: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 4096
01-27 13:57:40.655: I/sysproc(68): System server: starting Android runtime.
01-27 13:57:40.655: I/sysproc(68): System server: starting Android services.
01-27 13:57:40.655: I/SystemServer(68): Entered the Android system server!
01-27 13:57:40.685: I/sysproc(68): System server: entering thread pool.
01-27 13:57:40.755: I/SystemServer(68): Entropy Service
01-27 13:57:40.905: I/SystemServer(68): Power Manager
01-27 13:57:40.977: I/SystemServer(68): Activity Manager
01-27 13:57:41.075: I/ActivityManager(68): Memory class: 24
01-27 13:57:41.275: D/libEGL(78): egl.cfg not found, using default config
01-27 13:57:41.325: D/libEGL(78): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
01-27 13:57:41.375: W/zipro(78): Unable to open zip '/data/local/bootanimation.zip': No such file or directory
01-27 13:57:41.375: W/zipro(78): Unable to open zip '/system/media/bootanimation.zip': No such file or directory
01-27 13:57:41.765: I/ARMAssembler(68): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00000004_00000000 [ 22 ipp] (41 ins) at [0x22c988:0x22ca2c] in 8471468 ns
01-27 13:57:41.895: I/ARMAssembler(78): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000A01_00000000 [ 30 ipp] (51 ins) at [0x1c368:0x1c434] in 8052980 ns
01-27 13:57:42.595: I/SystemServer(68): Telephony Registry
01-27 13:57:42.628: I/SystemServer(68): Package Manager
01-27 13:57:42.745: I/Installer(68): connecting...
01-27 13:57:42.755: I/installd(35): new connection
01-27 13:57:43.065: I/PackageManager(68): Libs: android.test.runner:/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar javax.obex:/system/framework/javax.obex.jar
01-27 13:57:43.075: I/PackageManager(68): Features: android.hardware.camera android.hardware.camera.autofocus
01-27 13:57:43.616: D/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5213 objects / 231568 bytes in 182ms
01-27 13:57:44.535: W/PackageManager(68): Running ENG build: no pre-dexopt!
01-27 13:57:44.675: D/PackageManager(68): Scanning app dir /system/framework
01-27 13:57:45.135: D/PackageManager(68): Scanning app dir /system/app
01-27 13:57:45.725: D/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7548 objects / 375440 bytes in 160ms
01-27 13:57:47.885: D/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5511 objects / 301304 bytes in 165ms
01-27 13:57:49.235: D/PackageManager(68): Scanning app dir /data/app
01-27 13:57:50.326: D/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7079 objects / 378704 bytes in 191ms
01-27 13:57:50.747: W/PackageParser(68): No actions in intent filter at /data/app/ApiDemos.apk Binary XML file line #1718
01-27 13:57:50.775: W/PackageParser(68): No actions in intent filter at /data/app/ApiDemos.apk Binary XML file line #1724
01-27 13:57:50.816: W/PackageManager(68): Package com.example.android.apis desires unavailable shared library com.example.will.never.exist; ignoring!
01-27 13:57:50.885: D/PackageManager(68): Scanning app dir /data/app-private
01-27 13:57:50.885: I/PackageManager(68): Time to scan packages: 6.351 seconds
01-27 13:57:50.915: W/PackageManager(68): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.contacts
01-27 13:57:50.955: W/PackageManager(68): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
01-27 13:57:50.976: W/PackageManager(68): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x1be45)
01-27 13:57:50.985: W/PackageManager(68): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
01-27 13:57:50.985: W/PackageManager(68): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
01-27 13:57:51.065: W/PackageManager(68): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.settings
01-27 13:57:51.075: W/PackageManager(68): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.providers.contacts
01-27 13:57:51.075: W/PackageManager(68): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cp in package com.android.providers.contacts
01-27 13:57:51.085: W/PackageManager(68): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.ACCESS_GOOGLE_PASSWORD in package com.android.development
01-27 13:57:51.085: W/PackageManager(68): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.development
01-27 13:57:51.085: W/PackageManager(68): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES in package com.android.development
01-27 13:57:51.085: W/PackageManager(68): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.YouTubeUser in package com.android.development
01-27 13:57:51.675: D/dalvikvm(68): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5290 objects / 332160 bytes in 179ms
01-27 13:57:51.706: I/SystemServer(68): Account Manager
01-27 13:57:51.995: I/SystemServer(68): Content Manager
01-27 13:57:52.215: I/SystemServer(68): System Content Providers
01-27 13:57:52.236: I/ActivityThread(68): Publishing provider settings: com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider
01-27 13:57:52.556: I/SystemServer(68): Battery Service
01-27 13:57:52.615: I/SystemServer(68): Lights Service
01-27 13:57:52.615: I/SystemServer(68): Vibrator Service
01-27 13:57:52.655: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
01-27 13:57:52.655: D/qemud(38): created client 0x12f88 listening on fd 12
01-27 13:57:52.655: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'hw-control'
01-27 13:57:52.655: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 3
01-27 13:57:52.665: D/qemud(38): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 3
01-27 13:57:52.845: I/SystemServer(68): Alarm Manager
01-27 13:57:52.895: I/SystemServer(68): Init Watchdog
01-27 13:57:52.895: I/SystemServer(68): Sensor Service
01-27 13:57:52.928: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
01-27 13:57:52.928: D/qemud(38): created client 0xc038 listening on fd 13
01-27 13:57:52.948: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'sensors'
01-27 13:57:52.948: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 4
01-27 13:57:52.955: D/qemud(38): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 4
01-27 13:57:53.076: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 13
01-27 13:57:53.095: I/SystemServer(68): Window Manager
01-27 13:57:53.255: I/EventHub(68): New keyboard: device->id=0x10000 devname='qwerty2' propName='hw.keyboards.65536.devname' keylayout='/system/usr/keylayout/qwerty.kl'
01-27 13:57:53.255: I/EventHub(68): New device: path=/dev/input/event0 name=qwerty2 id=0x10000 (of 0x1) index=1 fd=51 classes=0x2f
01-27 13:57:53.296: E/EventHub(68): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
01-27 13:57:53.296: E/EventHub(68): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
01-27 13:57:53.305: I/KeyInputQueue(68): Device added: id=0x0, name=qwerty2, classes=2f
01-27 13:57:53.325: I/KeyInputQueue(68):   X: min=0 max=479 flat=0 fuzz=0
01-27 13:57:53.325: I/KeyInputQueue(68):   Y: min=0 max=799 flat=0 fuzz=0
01-27 13:57:53.325: I/KeyInputQueue(68):   Pressure: unknown values
01-27 13:57:53.325: I/KeyInputQueue(68):   Size: unknown values
01-27 13:57:53.335: I/KeyInputQueue(68): No virtual keys found
01-27 13:57:53.425: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
01-27 13:57:53.425: D/qemud(38): created client 0xc038 listening on fd 13
01-27 13:57:53.425: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'sensors'
01-27 13:57:53.425: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 5
01-27 13:57:53.438: D/qemud(38): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 5
01-27 13:57:53.550: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 13
01-27 13:57:53.575: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
01-27 13:57:53.575: D/qemud(38): created client 0xc038 listening on fd 13
01-27 13:57:53.595: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'sensors'
01-27 13:57:53.595: D/qemud(38): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 6
01-27 13:57:53.675: D/qemud(38): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 6
01-27 13:57:53.775: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
01-27 13:57:53.775: D/qemud(38): created client 0xc088 listening on fd 14
01-27 13:57:53.787: D/qemud(38): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 13
```

Answer (score 0):

The virtual device becomes corrupted if you previously closed it without pressing the (off sign button).

There may also be a run-time error in your program then if you are sure there is not then try deleting the current virtual device and create a new one. Also from its run properties disable boot animation then it may be faster

Comment: Well don't know what the exact course, but I found amongst the many lines of error code, that Eclipse had named the main activity wrong, so I correct that.  I also created a new virtual device, specifying NO SNAPSHOT (and WIPE DATA when starting device).  Then running the project and it was fine.  I should note that I can't 'shut down' the virtual device, I've left the device for 2 hrs and it's still spinning around 'shutting down' and this is after STARTing it and then trying to shut it straight down without running anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well don't know what the exact course, but I found amongst the many lines of error code, that Eclipse had named the main activity wrong (in the manifest), so I correct that.

I also created a new virtual device, specifying NO SNAPSHOT (and WIPE DATA when starting device).  Then running the project and it was fine.

I should note that I can't 'shut down' the virtual device, I've left the device for 2 hrs and it's still spinning around 'shutting down' and this is after STARTing it and then trying to shut it straight down without running anything.